# SQLAlchemy Async Join not bringing in columns

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying to join two tables using sqlalchemy, the query I am trying to acheive is:

```
SELECT *
FROM service_order
JOIN vendor ON service_order.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id
WHERE service_order.service_order_id = 898;
```

My current sqlalchemy statement below just generates an object <db.model.service_order.ServiceOrder> with columns only from the service_order table and instead of adding the columns into this object from the vendor table, creates a vendor object <db.model.vendor.Vendor> as one of the values.

```
from typing import List, Sequence, Dict, Union

from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy import func

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, joinedload, lazyload, selectinload

from api.model import CreateServiceOrderRequest
from db.model import ServiceOrder as DBServiceOrder
from db.model import ServiceOrderItem as DBServiceOrderItem
from db.model import Vendor as DBVendor
from db.engine import DatabaseSession as AsyncSession
from ..exceptions import DBRecordNotFoundException, InvalidPropertyException

from core.domains.service_order.service_order_model import ServiceOrderModel


async def get_service_order_by_id(
    session: AsyncSession, service_order_id: int
) -> ServiceOrderModel:
    async with session:
        statement = (
            select(DBServiceOrder)
            .options(
                joinedload(DBServiceOrder.service_order_item).joinedload(
                    DBServiceOrderItem.service_order_item_receive
                ),
            )
            .join(DBVendor, DBServiceOrder.vendor_id == DBVendor.vendor_id)
            .where(DBServiceOrder.service_order_id == service_order_id)
        )
        result = await session.scalars(statement)
        service_order = result.first()


    return service_order
```

Below are my DB models for both service_order and vendor.

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional, List

from sqlalchemy import func, ForeignKey, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

from .base_model import BaseModel


class ServiceOrder(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "service_order"

    service_order_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    vendor_id: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("vendor.vendor_id"))

    vendor: Mapped["Vendor"] = relationship(
        "Vendor", lazy="selectin", back_populates="service_order"
    )
    service_order_item: Mapped[List["ServiceOrderItem"]] = relationship(
        "ServiceOrderItem", back_populates="service_order"
    )

from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional, List

from sqlalchemy import func, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

from .base_model import BaseModel


class Vendor(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "vendor"

    vendor_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    company_name: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(200))
 

    component: Mapped[List["Component"]] = relationship(back_populates="vendor")
    motor: Mapped[List["Motor"]] = relationship(foreign_keys="Motor.vendor_id")
    motor_field_track: Mapped[List['MotorFieldTrack']] = relationship('MotorFieldTrack', back_populates='vendor')
    service_order: Mapped[List['ServiceOrder']] = relationship('ServiceOrder', back_populates='vendor')
    motor_order: Mapped[List['MotorOrder']] = relationship('MotorOrder', back_populates='vendor')
```

I've tried various combinations of joinedloading, lazyloading, joininload but nothing seems to work. Instead of creating an object with all the columns it keeps creating a vendor object instead of the columns from that table. How can I return one object with all the columns from both tables? Even better if I plan to pick and choose what columns from the second table, how do I achieve that as well?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#selecting-individual-attributes

Comment: @GordThompson I tried that but it still just keeps adding vendor as an object under service_order, rather than brining in columns...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd only want to do this if you were fetching thousands of records or something because you are almost working against the ORM.  Note that you must use `execute` rather than `scalars` to access the tuple that contains other "columns".  Also if you aren't using the ORM functionality than you will not want to use `joinedload`.

```py
async def get_service_order_by_id(
    session: AsyncSession, service_order_id: int
) -> ServiceOrderModel:
    async with session:
        statement = (
            select(DBServiceOrder, DBVendor.company_name)
            .join(DBVendor, DBServiceOrder.vendor_id == DBVendor.vendor_id)
            .where(DBServiceOrder.service_order_id == service_order_id)
        )
       
        result = await session.execute(statement)
        service_order, vender_company_name = result.first()
```

The conventional ORM way looks like this.  Use `joinload` to simultaneously populate and attach the `.vendor` object onto the `server_order` object all with one `SQL` query.  Coming from regular `SQL` this sounds crazy but eventually you end up doing this accumulation and grouping manually anyways in most cases:

```py
async def get_service_order_by_id(
    session: AsyncSession, service_order_id: int
) -> ServiceOrderModel:
    async with session:
        statement = (
            select(DBServiceOrder)
            .join(DBServiceOrder.vendor)
            .where(DBServiceOrder.service_order_id == service_order_id)
            .options(joinedload(DBServiceOrder.vendor))
        )
        
        result = await session.scalars(statement)  
        service_order = result.first()
        # without joinedload above this would trigger a SQL
        # select in the background to load this
        vendor = server_order.vendor
```

## Regarding balancing performance and convenience

> Lets say I go with the approach of loading the vendor object under the
> service_order object. When returning this data back via an API to the
> front end, what is the proper restful response. Do I flatten out this
> vendor object and put it all into one response along with service
> order. Or do I provide it as a nested object within service order?

It sounds like a simple question but it can get complicated.  You must strike a balance between maintainability, convenience and performance (both # of requests and how requests can be cached) based on how your consumers will use your API.  The theoretical approach would be to not nest it and return an id and submit another HTTP request to get the vendor.  The practical approach would be to return some often needed data, ie. the vendor's `company_name` and `id` and either return more if requested using the same endpoint, ie. `/services_orders/58?include=vendor`, or require the consumer make another request to get the full vendor, ie. `/vendors/456`.

Regarding trimming down how many "nested" columns to include I don't think it would make a big difference for performance and then you have all these hard coded columns stuffed into your service methods.  For example what if you want to add a column or change the columns returned?  Now you have to adjust a method at the core of your system.  You obviously don't want to return your entire data model on every request but a simple join especially for a single row would make no difference.

This is some psuedo code.  If you need to start including and excluding varying data you might have additional end points OR
expand the use of include and have multiple api methods.  Especially if your api is successful and you want to optimize things you could add a with and without vendor to the core service itself later.  In the meantime you have a core general purpose method that can be used throughout your code base without hard coding the columns, ie. `service_order_api.get_by_id`.

```py
def get_service_order_endpoint(request, db_session):
    service_order_id = get_requested_id(request)
    includes = get_requested_includes(request)
    # This api just gets the vendor no matter what.
    service_order = service_order_api.get_by_id(db_session, service_order_id)
    # This api either includes the full vendor or 
    # just include a dict like {..., "vendor": {"id": 456, "name": "ACME"}}
    service_order_dict = service_order_serialization_api.to_dict(service_order, include_full_vendor='vendor' in includes) 
    return to_json(service_order_dict)
```

Stripe for example uses the `expand` parameter:

[expanding_objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects)

Comment: Makes sense, I did have a followup. Lets say I go with the approach of loading the vendor object under the service_order object. When returning this data back via an API to the front end, what is the proper restful response. Do I flatten out this vendor object and put it all into one response along with service order. Or do I provide it as a nested object within service order?

Comment: I tried to add an explanation at bottom of answer but it is a complicated topic, probably too big for this question.  We could talk about it on chat later if you thought it would help.